# Question about relativity

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

I know when mass becomes massive we need general relativity. My question is why do we need to incorporate special relativity since the mass is not in high speed .Cant we have Newtons law of gravitation for massive objects(curvature of spacetime without special relativity)
Or we can say
Curvature of spacetime without special relativity

Or lets say curvature of Space, not time

Comment: *"I know when mass becomes massive we need general relativity."* What does this mean?

Comment: How would that work? Newton's law doesn't "know" about spacetime, or spacetime curvature.

Comment: Special Relativity is the foundation of all physics and it establishes an important idea that time needs to be treated just like space.  Because of this, all physical laws need to be written in a way that this fact is true -- such as using 4-vectors.

Comment: General relativity is a theory of gravity. See [Why can't I do this to get infinite energy?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/178417/37364). Or this [What is General Relativity?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DYq774z4dws)

Comment: @K7PEH Fair point, but let's try to avoid writing answers in comments. ;)

Comment: Related: [Can there be general relativity without special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/400910/123208)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What has general relativity got to do with special relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/492846/)

Comment: @ACuriousMind - It means if an object is massive enough, we need general relativity to explain what we see.

Comment: @PM2Ring There is the seed of a good question hidden in there, but little incentive to provide an answer to a question that looks like it will be closed very shortly (as I naively did yesterday).  As a "counterbalance" to the low-gravity scenario used to match GR to Newtonian gravitation, there is a "high-G, low-speed" analysis which is well worth looking at (mostly because the low-speed approximation turns 4-tensors into manageable scalar equations).  Some here might be familiar with the author . . . https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/einstein/